# asp.net ApiController wait for request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I built an ApiController application. My tests are running fine, the only problem is that I can't make it wait for a request. I want to run the application in Visual Studio and try an external AJAX request. However, when I run the application in Visual Studio, it run the whole application.

Here is my controller:

```
public class PostController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/test")]
    public string Post([FromBody] Data m)
    {
        PostingToCL post = new PostingToCL();
        string postReturn = post.Post();
        return string.Format(postReturn);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to make it wait I run an external html file that will call this API. Does it make sense? How can I do it?

Comment: Hi, I'd give you a hand. I'd need more context of how your project looks like.
How you are running it. And how does your request look like.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm learning ApiController. I want that it works like an API, so I can call it from another websites. The problem is if I click run from PostController.cs file, it will run the Post method. I thought it should just run from a request with type: POST

Answer (score 1):

Check you route. I like to put route on the whole controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController: Controller{
    [HttpPost]  
    public string Post([FromBody] Data m)
    {
        PostingToCL post = new PostingToCL();
        string postReturn = post.Post();
        return string.Format(postReturn);
    }
}
```

Give me a more specific example and use case.
I'm thinking this is what you you are looking for:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

I highly suggest to look at an example application:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Download the source code and run it:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sample-code-of-Getting-c56ccb28

Then debug the application on the back end:
Your controllers would be under Controllers folder.
See the project structure and data flow. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I have done it and is running fine. But my code like the example, the AJAX request is inside the same project. I want to run my controller (API) and let it listening until have a AJAX request from an external file (not in the same project)

Comment: Let's put in this way. I want  to run my application, but I do not want it call the [httppost]. Every time I run the project it automatically calls my [httppost] method.

Comment: it still is unclear. some more examples or code will help.

Comment: Okay... I open my project, then I click "Start Debugging" in Visual Studio. It opens the firefox in my localhost page. It also calls the method "Post" from my PostController class. I do not want to call this method

Comment: Check the answer. I suspect the route is routed to default to your controller.

Comment: I changed to put the route in whole controller, but still the same issue

Comment: what about your WebApiConfig file? what is the HttpConfiguration like

Comment: It's odd, but if I run in chrome, it doesn't happen. Might be cache?

Comment: Cache is always a good thing to clear. maybe even disable it in browser settings. Also what is the client request code. Browsers could behave differently.

Comment: How can I check the client request code? I didn't know that a localhost application could have cache

Comment: Who is the caller of your Ajax? It is some .html or chtml that is sent to the user's browser when requested from the server. Then displayed in the user's browser. It can be any machine's browser. Since your application is only on localhost for now you are both server IIS and client your browser.

Comment: The caller is an html file from a domain that I own. It's working fine when I run my project in chrome from Visual Studio.